# Get top facebook pages by category

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a music-related app, and I would like to receive top 50 Facebook fan-pages under "musician" category. Is there any way to retrieve  most followed fan pages under certain category from Facebook?

There is a website has this type of list; (I am not affiliated with them)
http://www.socialbakers.com/statistics/facebook/pages/total/entertainment/music-industry/ but not sure if they have been using Facebook API or some other technique.

Instead of going 3rd party I would prefer using Facebook API for this type of purposes if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that´s not possible. You can only search for Pages by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search

There is no "top list", and you can´t get Pages by category.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. While I was doing more research on this topic, I saw there is a 3rd party website already created a list I want. (Please see my updated answer) Seems like Facebook has no plan releasing something like that?

Comment: those 3rd party websites usually just add pages manually and update the likes with a cron job on a daily basis. if facebook has a plan releasing something like that....well, that is a question only facebook can answer, but i doubt it ;) - right now there is no way to do that with the api.